# Updating variables in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I set `lower_case_table_names = 2` in `/etc/my.cnf` file. I also updated this variable in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. After setting the variable I restarted mysql server, but still the value is 0, when I use `SHOW VARIABLES`.

I'm using MySQL 5.5. Any Ideas what else needs to be done?

**UPDATE**

my.cnf content:-

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
lower_case_table_names = 2
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `grep -i lower_case_table_names /etc/* /etc/mysql/*` please?

Comment: The output is:-
`/etc/my.cnf:lower_case_table_names = 2`
`/etc/my.cnf.wba.bak:lower_case_table_names = 1`
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf:lower_case_table_names = 2`
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-old:lower_case_table_names=1`

Comment: Edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Updated my.cnf content. I've tried both `/etc/init.d/mysql start or stop` and MySQL Workbench to restart servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the file there are multiple places where config files are also loaded.

`!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`:
Check every file in this directory if the setting is overwritten by one:

```
grep -i lower_case_table_names /etc/mysql/conf.d/*
```

or check the files manually and search for the config value.

`# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.`: Check the `.my.cnf` of the user that runs the `mysql` daemon, maybe there is this setting overwritten.

Find out the uid of the user with:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

The first row is the uid. Find the user's home directory with:

```
grep <uid> /etc/passwd
```

the 6th `:`-separated string is the home directory. When in this directory is a `.my.cnf`, this file is loaded.

Stop the mysql daemon with `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`. And check if the daemon is stopped with `pgrep mysql` and `pgrep mysqld`. If the pgrep commands still return pids then kill those pids with `kill`. Sometimes `mysql` needs a very long time to stop with huge databases, thats normal. So first wait before killing things.

If you are sure `mysql` is stopped and all config files are cleaned from this config value, then start `mysql` again with `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and check the value.

Comment: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/*` doesn't have `lower_case_table_names` setting.
`ps -ef | grep mysql` returns 2 uid `mysql` for `mysqld` and my own user name  for `mysql`.
`grep mysql /etc/passwd` returns /nonexistent
Checked .my.cnf my own user also added the setting to it, but still no avail.
Do you think `/etc/init.d/mysql` script will help?

Answer (score -1):

For those using Windows with the Workbench 6.1, here's how I found to make this work.  Select your schema and in the query box, enter:  `set global max_allowed_packet = 1073741824`. You can use a lower number, but it must be a multiple of 1024.  This is the largest value allowed (1 gig).  Once you do this, SHOW VARIABLES doesn't show the change :(, but apparently, it does change.  Immediately (may not be necessary) after executing the above statement, go to Server/Import.  The error "... 9932: MySQL server has gone away" no longer comes up.

Comment: ???????????????